# How to scrape a table with rvest and xpath?

Tags: r, xpath, web-scraping, rvest

using the following [documentation](http://www.r-bloggers.com/using-rvest-to-scrape-an-html-table/) i have been trying to scrape a series of tables from marketwatch.com

here is the one represented by the code bellow:

[image]

The link and xpath are already included in the code:

```
url <- "http://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/IRS/profile"
valuation <- url %>%
  html() %>%
  html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="maincontent"]/div[2]/div[1]') %>%
  html_table()
valuation <- valuation[[1]]
```

I get the following error:

```
Warning message:
'html' is deprecated.
Use 'read_html' instead.
See help("Deprecated")
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: remove the `html()` and replace with `read_html()`

Comment: that's not an error, it's a warning. your code will still run with that warning.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That website doesn't use an html table, so `html_table()` can't find anything. It actaully uses `div` classes `column` and `data lastcolumn`.

So you can do something like

```r
url <- "http://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/IRS/profile"
valuation_col <- url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes(xpath='//*[@class="column"]')
    
valuation_data <- url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes(xpath='//*[@class="data lastcolumn"]')
```

Or even

```r
url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes(xpath='//*[@class="section"]')
```

To get you most of the way there.

Please also read their [terms of use](http://www.marketwatch.com/support/disclaimer.asp) - particularly 3.4.

Comment: how you find the xpath (there is tool to find it, can you add it to the answer)

Comment: Right-click on the element and select 'inspect'. Then just read the html