# Scraping data from finviz with R - Structure for

Tags: r, for-loop, web-scraping

I am new using R and this is my first question. I apologize if it has been solved before but I haven't found a solution.

By using below code, that I found here, I can get data from and specific subsector from Finviz screener:

```
library (rvest)    

url <- read_html("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=geo_usa,ind_specialtyindustrialmachinery&o=industry")

tables <- html_nodes(url,"table")
screener <- tables %>% html_nodes("table") %>% .[11] %>% 
  html_table(fill=TRUE) %>% data.frame()

head(screener)
```

It was a bit difficult to find the table number bud I did. My question refers to lists with more than 20, like the one I am using at the example. They use &r=1, &r=21, &r=41, &r=61 at the end of each url.

How could I create in this case the structure?

```
i=0
for(z in ...){
```

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: .[11] is consistent in all links? I have checked it for table &1, &r21 it's not present.

Comment: Yes, the link https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=geo_usa,ind_specialtyindustrialmachinery&o=industry&r=1 works.      Maybe you cannot access it if you're not registered...

Comment: I am taking about `%>% .[11] %>% ` this step. the number 11 is working fine for the current [url](https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=geo_usa,ind_specialtyindustrialmachinery&o=industry) but not for &1 url

Comment: I don't know why, but it works for me. I just checked again.

Comment: the link is working fine, the concerned it `tables<- read_html("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=geo_usa,ind_specialtyindustrialmachinery&o=industry&r=1")
  tables<-read_html(stringr::str_c(url,"&",tableNo))
  screener <- tables %>% 
    html_nodes("table") %>% 
    .[11]` the output will be `screener
{xml_nodeset (1)}
[1] <table style="border-collapse: collapse; table-layout: fixed;" cellpadding="0"><tr>\n<td style="position: re ...` which is not data points you required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update script based on new table number and link:**

```
library (rvest) 
library(stringr)

url <- "https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=geo_usa,ind_specialtyindustrialmachinery&o=industry"

TableList<-c("1","21","41","61") # table list 

GetData<-function(URL,tableNo){

  cat('\n',"Running For table",tableNo,'\n', 'Weblink Used:',stringr::str_c(url,"&r=",tableNo),'\n')

  tables<-read_html(stringr::str_c(url,"&r=",tableNo)) #get data from webpage based on table numbers
  screener <- tables %>% 
    html_nodes("table") %>% 
   .[17] %>% 
    html_table(fill=TRUE) %>% 
    data.frame()
  return(screener)
} 


AllData<- lapply(TableList, function(x) GetData(URL=url, tableNo = x)) # getting all data in form of list
```

Here is one approach using `stringr` and `lapply`:

```
library (rvest) 
library(stringr)

url <- "https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=geo_usa,ind_specialtyindustrialmachinery&o=industry" # base url

TableList<-c("1","21","41","61") # table number list 

GetData<-function(URL,tableNo){

  cat('\n',"Running For table",tableNo,'\n', 'Weblink Used:',stringr::str_c(url,"&",tableNo),'\n')

  tables<-read_html(stringr::str_c(url,"&",tableNo)) #get data from webpage based on table numbers

  screener <- tables %>% 
    html_nodes("table") %>% 
    .[11] %>% # check
    html_table(fill=TRUE) %>% 
    data.frame()
  return(screener)
} 

AllData<- lapply(TableList, function(x) GetData(URL=url, tableNo = x)) # list of dataframes
```

However please check for `.[11]` number as it will be changed for these URLs(URL with &1, &21, etc). It is working fine for the base URL. Data is not present for the URL with &1, &21, etc at 11th index. Please change accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much Nirbhay. Yes, that table number is not working with the function.I will try to find another way...

Comment: The table numbers are not working as there is no data at 11 number tables in the URLs. Checked table number `17` has the data. So just replace the 11 with 17. It will work. In the next comment, I have given the output of head(screener,2).

Comment: `head(screener,2)
   X1     X2                            X3          X4                             X5      X6         X7  X8    X9    X10     X11
1 No. Ticker                       Company      Sector                       Industry Country Market Cap P/E Price Change  Volume
2   1   AIMC Altra Industrial Motion Corp. Industrials Specialty Industrial Machinery     USA      1.99B   - 28.12  5.00% 454,656`

Comment: Thanks again. I have tried with [17] but it shows only the second table to me. I don't know if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: checked again it is showing correct data to me, what is the output of `lapply(AllData,length)` for you? In my case AllData has 11 elements in each .

Comment: Yes, it gives 11 data in each one to me as well, but if I type for example head(screener,25) it shows only rows from 21 to 40 (second url).

Comment: Understood your concern. Updating answer in few mins. The issue is the reference link.

Comment: @CarlosFC Refer the updated script, It should give you desired results.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works very well now. Just two questions. Is there another way to avoid finding the table number when working with html_nodes? How can I convert Alldata to an unique table?

Comment: @CarlosFC you can use `AllDataCombined<-do.call( rbind, AllData)` to get data in a unique table. Instead of tables ID you can use methods using xpath. you can refer [Similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35707534/how-to-scrape-a-table-with-rvest-and-xpath) types of question on SO.

Comment: @CarlosFC Glad to help. As my suggestion suitably answers your question, click the tick mark to accept it as the chosen answer and upvote it.

Comment: After working more with the code you gave me (it works very well) I realized that the TableList is fine when I need to get not many records but when I need to scrap for example 3751 records (https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=sec_financial) I cannot type all pages number because it would be endless. I was wondering if it would be another way to avoid typing all page numbers. Each page number is previous+20.

Comment: You can look for RSelenium package for better uses